# Is it possible to customize the Backlogs view

Tags: azure, azure-devops, customization, devops

We are using Azure DevOps as an agile project management tool. I'm trying to customize the tool to our needs.

Under "Boards -> Backlogs" the user stories & tasks for a project are listed (see picture). However, in that view are only planned or ongoing user stories shown but no completed user stories. While I can create a query that also shows completed ones, I would like to make them appear in this particular view.

In addition, I changed the columns/fields which should be shown by default in this view for our project across different teams/users. 
For both, I am trying to find a solution but haven't been successful yet.

Appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The displayed columns are specific to a user and there isn't a way to force a view for the backlog.

The only way I am aware of to see closed items on the backlog view is to have the user story as a child of a feature.  The feature must not be closed and your backlog view has to be at the Features level.